# Get a line of space-separated integers from stdio without knowing how much they are (C++)

Tags: c++, io

I'm dealing with a competitive programming challenge in which I have to take a line of space-separated integers from standard input, put them into an array, and treat them in a certain way. The problem is that I don't know how many integer I may get in each test case.
In case I know, my code would be like:

```
int n; // number of integers;
int arr[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];
```

In case I don't have 'n', how would I achieve the same thing?

Comment: `int arr[n]` where `n` is a variable set at run time is not allowed in standard C++ - although some (not all) C++ compilers support it as a non-standard extension.  Avoid it.  Use `std::vector<int>` instead. By default it is created containing no elements but your code can append every value it reads to the vector.  Then you can process the set of integers in almost any way you can imagine (as long as you stick within capabilities of the vector type, obviously). The only limitations on number of elements that a `std::vector` can have are available or addressable memory of your host system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector<int>` is basically a dynamically-sized array of ints. You can keep adding stuff to it and it will grow as necessary.  If you are given a number of elements as the first input, you can do something like:

```
std::vector<int> items;

int count;
std::cin >> count;

// Preallocates room for the items. This is not necessary, it's just an optimization.
items.reserve(count);

while (count > 0) {
    int item;
    std::cin >> item;
    items.push_back(item);
    --count;
}
```

If you are not given the number of items, just read until reading fails:

```
std::vector<int> items;
int item;

while (std::cin >> item) {
    items.push_back(item);
}
```

Comment: Pretty helpful. What if they are multiple lines and each line of space-separated integer would go to a different vector?

Comment: @TaoufiqJmari A combination of `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

Use vectors beacuse vectors are dynamic in size. Keep pushing elements into vector until inputs are there.

```
std::vector<int> v; 
int temp; 
while (std::cin >> temp) { 
     v.push_back(temp); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**When you will be given the value of `n`. You can follow any of the following two steps:**

*Step: 1*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n; // Input n
    vector<int>vv(n); // It will declare a vector(similar to an array) of size n
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> vv[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Step: 2*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, number;
    cin >> n; // Input n
    vector<int>vv; // It will declare an empty vector
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> number; // Take a number as input
        vv.push_back(number); // Put the input to the last of the vector
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**When you will not be given the value of `n`:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    vector<int>vv; // It will declare an empty vector.
    while(cin >> number)
    {
        vv.push_back(number); // Push(put) the input to the back(end/last) of the vector
    }

    /* In case of reading input from a file,
    the loop will continue until the end of the file.

    When you'll try it from console, you need to enter
    end-of-file command from keyboard.*/

    return 0;
}
```